# Parse jsdoc/tsdoc in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this Interface property:

```
  /**
   * If enabled the log output will be printed locally in console.
   * The log call line will not be overwritten unless {@link ILoggerConfig.useLoggerProcessors} is true
   */
  printToConsole?: boolean;
```

In the generated docs it makes `ILoggerConfig.useLoggerProcessors` a clickable link but vscode intellisense doesn't :

[image: intellisense]

The link part does not disturb me but vscode intellisense keeps the verbose `{@link ILoggerConfig.useLoggerProcessors}` part and when more than 2 other properties/classes/methods are referenced it is hard to read.

Can I make vscode parse the comments? I have searched for a [tsdoc extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=tsdoc&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) but have found none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug as of VS Code 1.31. The following issues are tracking it:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16498
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29617

Markdown links in JSDocs are already supported (but only to urls, not to symbols).